# why do I bind to ip 0 failed?

Tags: django

I know if I use IP 0, I will bind to all public IP in my local network.But actually when I run python manage.py runserver 0:8000, it says:

```
[Errno 11004],get addrinfo failed.
```

But in the past, I can ran it successfully. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: i think it should be `0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: it is so strange, the official doc says 0 can be shortcut for 0.0.0.0

Comment: what doc? maybe 0 is valid only if no port is specified

Comment: I don't see this mentioned in the docs. Are you able to cite where this idea came from?

Answer (score 0):

Is'nt it possible `manage.py runserver 0:8000` ?
I did it and it works well - in django 1.11

When did your Error occur?

[image]

sorry for helpless answer. I want to comment out but I can't because of my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> `[Errno 11004],get addrinfo failed.`

Above error means that the provided hostname cannot be resolved or is unavailable at the moment.

This could be due to various reasons.
From the information that you provided it appears that the reason can be you not exiting the previous `runserver` call properly resulting in not proper exit of the process, which in turn means that the port access is still with the previous process, and you are not allowed to run the call.

To solve the issue, you should check for all the process on the used port.
[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port) might help. Find the pid of the process which is holding that port and kill it.